# positioning of divs - CSS

Tags: css, html, css-transitions

I was trying to play around with HTML and CSS.

My divs needs to be positioned different from what I mentioned below.

[JS fiddle link for the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/sudharsanam/6wzms/)

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div{
    float:left;
    background-color:green;
    width:10px;
    margin:1px;
}
body{
    width:50px;
}
</style>  
<body>
<div style="height:20px"></div>
<div style="height:30px"></div> 
<div style="height:40px"></div>
<div style="height:35px"></div>
<div style="height:55px;background-color:red"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

I want the red box and any new boxes if needs to be rendered also to be rendered in the second row starting from left, just below the corresponding first row elements.(with a specific margins between elements)

Conditions:

Width of the rectangle is always same; only the height differs.

**Assuming in my jsfiddle  example with the given width only 4 elements can occupy
a row. so, 5th element should automatically start from next row and get positioned below the first row elements accordingly.**

What I want is something like this.

[image]

Can somebody please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance,

Sudharsanam.N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to obtain a "pinterest-like" effect for your divs you need some javascript, check out this jQuery plugin: http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Exactly for what I have been looking out for Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are welcome, if you like please flag my answer as correct. thx

Answer (score 1):

Add `clear:left` to the div where you need to add break

```
  div:nth-child(5){
    clear:left
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6wzms/4/)**

Comment: Thanks for immediate response; But what I want is not this. I want the red element to be immediately rendered below first row first element(say 0.5px down or even 0px down should be fine). Sorry for not being very clear on the question at first place.

Comment: What happens is it gets positioned below the largest element.. I dont want this to happen. I want it to be positioned accordingly!!!

Comment: You need to use masonry for that\

Answer (score 0):

Use display inline block instead of float left:

```
div{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;
    width:10px;
    margin:1px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
body{
    width:60px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c3Fxj/)

I think you should use JS to exactly get what you want.